# cURL blank return

Tags: php, curl

I have checked all the postings of everything I could and found no solutions to my issue. And unfortunately I am quite new to php so my knowledge is pretty slim. Therefore I pose my question:

Given the following code, why is the page blank when it should be echo'ing either the curl_error or $content?

```
<?php

$url = "http://thenewboston.org/";

function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  echo curl_error($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
    $content = curl_get_contents( $url );
    echo $content;
?>
```

This not the specific URL I need to connect to howver at the moment I am not able to pull data from any URL I try.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running it on an external server? I am only running it on Xampp thought I wouldn't think that would matter

Comment: Please make youre you have php_curl installed. Prepend something like        ```echo 'curl Extension is: '.( function_exists('curl_version') ? 'present' : 'not installed or disabled');```      to your script

Comment: ran on ubuntu vm. try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the beginning

Comment: I do have curl installed and enabled, version 7.36.0 for reference.  Tried the `error_reporting(E_ALL);` with no result :P

Comment: Any reason you're not using `file_get_contents()`? Does your server have `fopen_url` disabled?

Comment: Bundled packagers such as xampp, wamp have problem with curl, try to install Apache, PHP separately and see if it is working or not.

Answer (score 4):

`http://thenewboston.org/` redirects to `https://buckysroom.org/`, and that site requires SSL version 3. Add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Barmar`’s answer is correct about the SSL. But here is my refactoring of your code with a few more curl options set that I use as a default in cases like this. Note the user agent is most often the biggest reason why `curl` attempts fail so I have `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` set to a standard Firefox string, but feel free to change that to be anything else you feel might be a good user agent setting:

```
$url = "http://thenewboston.org/";

function curl_get_contents($url) {
  $curl_timeout = 5;
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $curl_timeout);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
  $data = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  return $data;
}

$content = curl_get_contents( $url );

echo $content;
```